# Ubuntu 12.04 tilts when trying to open large excel file with libreoffice or matlab

Tags: memory

I have an xlsx-file of size 27.3MB and when I try to open it either in Libreoffice or Matlab the whole system slows down

My processor is AMD Sempron(tm) 140 Processor (should be about 2.7Ghz)
Memory I have about 1.7GB

Any ideas? I opened this file in Windows no problem...of course it took a few seconds to load but Ubuntu freezes with this file completely...smaller files of size 3MB, 5MB etc open just fine...

thnx for support =)

Comment: what do you need to do with it: view or edit?

Comment: I need to view it. And also I need to import the data from it to Matlab...I found out there might be something in the excel file itself...because I made another excel file of size 37MB and Libreoffice did open it.....strange

Comment: To view it you may be able to use an online conversion tool (PDF perhaps). I don't have one to recommend but it's pretty quick to try a couple. In order to import it to matlab, you may have to get creative. I'd check if the file isn't corrupt, or if it contains something that LO or Matlab can't handle.

Comment: RAM upgrade is recommended.